# How to refference a line of code in BitBucket from a selected commit but the line is not part of the change

Tags: bitbucket

We try to create a link to a selected line of code, but the code section where that line appears (and we what to show) is in a previous commit.

That section ***IS NOT part of the changes reflected in that commit***, but is in the repository snapshot for that commit.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a way to do that, the trick is to reference your source code by using the commit whole hash as a branch name.

i.e. The following link gives you the source code of a public BitBucket repository in it's master branch:

https://bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/wally-learns-git/src/master/

but if you replace the **"master"** for the **"*<commit hash>*"** and more over, concatenate the **"*<file path>*"** and append **"#lines-*<the line number>*"**, i.e.:

https://bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/wally-learns-git/src/6382d80b420b0a4e5aae204e2d9401021d2f677d/LICENSE.txt#lines-7

You get a link to the source code file, positioned showing the line, and this line remarked from the rest.

Notice that, if you look in that particular commit the **LICENCE.txt** file was not modified so not included in the commit changes display:

https://bitbucket.org/teamsinspace/wally-learns-git/commits/6382d80b420b0a4e5aae204e2d9401021d2f677d